# gradle sync Error "cvc-complex-type.2.4.a:"

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I have installed the latest android studio and I try to sync an old project that I download from GitHub and I get this Error:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'base-extension'. One of '{codename, tag}' is expected.
```

and This

```
CVC-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'base-extension'. No child element is expected at this point.
```

Comment: Did you ever find the answer?  Trying to figure this out myself.

Answer (score 0):

Set the NDK manually, and downgrade it to 21 or lower.